# How to implement TorchDrift's Drift Detection for Monitoring Separate Text Embedding Distributions Across Multiple Topics?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, topic-modeling, drift

I'm working on a project involving text data with multiple topics, and I want to use the Kernel Maximum Mean Discrepancy (Kernel MMD) for drift detection on text embeddings **for each topic separately**.

I want to use the Kernel Maximum Mean Discrepancy (Kernel MMD) for drift detection on each topic's text embeddings. To do this, I'd like to use TorchDrift's Kernel MMD implementation (`torchdrift.detectors.KernelMMDDriftDetector()`) and creating separate detectors for each topic. However, I'm stuck because the documentation for the `torchdrift.utils.fit(...)` function doesn't provide clear instructions on how it works and how to train multiple KernelMMDDriftDetector instances with different datasets.

The code snippet provided to me has been sent for me to draw inspiration from. However, the sender designed it to operate in a text classification context, whereas my goal is to perform Drift Detection on unlabeled embeddings, for each available topic. In other words, I don't understand how to "expand for 'n' topics" this implementation:

```
# ...

my_dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_x,tensor_y)
my_dataloader = DataLoader(my_dataset)

class MyIdentityModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyIdentityModule, self).__init__()
        self.identity = torch.nn.Identity()

    def forward(self, X):
        Y = self.identity(X)
        return Y

my_feature_extractor = MyIdentityModule()

drift_detector = torchdrift.detectors.KernelMMDDriftDetector()

torchdrift.utils.fit(my_dataloader, my_feature_extractor, drift_detector, device="cpu")

deg_np_x = X_test_emb
deg_np_y = X_test_predicted

tensor_x = torch.Tensor(deg_np_x) 
tensor_y = torch.Tensor(deg_np_y)

score = drift_detector(tensor_x)
p_val = drift_detector.compute_p_value(tensor_x)
score, p_val

if p_val < 0.05:
    print("1: Drift Detected")
else:
    print("0: Drift NOT Detected")
```

In this reference code, a Module that computes the identity is created because it is needed by the fit function, even if I already have the text embeddings ready.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation or can provide guidance on how to tackle this issue? I hope my question is clear, and I appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide.